# remove text between delimiters, multiple times on each line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, non-greedy

I need to remove text between the delimiters "<" and ">", but there are multiple instances of these on each line of my text file.

For example, I want to turn this:

```
person 1, person 2<email2@mail.com>, person 3<email3@mail.com>, person 4<email4@mail.com>`
```

Into this:

```
person 1, person 2, person 3, person 4
```

I've tried to use a few things, including sed:

`sed -e 's/<.*>//' filename.csv`

but this removes everything between the first `<` and the last `>` giving the result `person 1, person 2`.

Comment: The regexp `sed 's/<.*>//g' file` will work but only if there is only one email address , because the `.*` is greedy and matches the longest string possible. However if you use `sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' file` instead, the regexp removes every string that starts with `<` and anything else upto the next `>`.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you for taking the time to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

you can use a negated character class in your regex:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' filename.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join the dark side, Perl lets you specify non-greedy wildcards with `?`:

```
perl -pe 's/<.*?>//g' filename.csv
```

Comment: This worked great as well!  I definitively appreciate the dark side.